# Where are the pre-indigo wiki pages for packages?

Tags: ros, wiki

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just noticed (2017-02-01) that for a large number of wiki pages the version rockers at the top of the page no longer show any ROS versions older than Indigo. Some packages I'm certain have been around for some time: [ros_comm](http://wiki.ros.org/ros_comm), [actionlib](http://wiki.ros.org/actionlib) and [fanuc](http://wiki.ros.org/fanuc).

Has something been turned off?

---

Edit: the wiki has been rather unstable for the past few days as well (`500` errors, taking a long time to render pages, etc). Is/Was that related or just a coincidence?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/253671/where-are-the-pre-indigo-wiki-pages-for-packages?/) by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 86574 on 2017-02-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is likely the result of the merge (and subsequent deployment) of [ros-infrastructure/roswiki#169](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/roswiki/pull/169) (`hydro` hidden in [ros-infrastructure/roswiki@08ecba51](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/roswiki/commit/08ecba512c9b6fefe24923472620fc62f0ff846e)).

Apparenty I've not been paying attention and `groovy` and older have been hidden by the rocker for quite some time now.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-02-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-03**:
I'll wait some time for a more authorative answer.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-02-03**:
This seems consistent with http://status.ros.org/incidents/lxh6f9rcl1bg

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-03**:
Yes, I saw the commit and figured that was the cause for the `500`s.